# How to Remove Strings between two Parenthesis in Unix

Tags: sed

I have a requirement like i have to remove the strings or numbers between two Parenthesis in a file. I used `sed` command but it is working on a single line. My opening Parenthesis is in one line and the closing parenthesis is in other line. How can i do it?

I tried this command using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'
```

but this works only when My opening and closing parenthesis are on the same line.

For Example:-

Input file:

```
select a
,b
,c
FROM ABCD
(select e
,f
,g
,h FROM XYZ)
```

Output should be:

```
select a
,b
,c
FROM ABCD
```

---

Comment: What have you tried - what modifications of the original sed command did you attempt? What were the results?

Comment: For new GNU sed use `-z` option

Comment: I tried using sed command

sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g' <filename>>

this worked for single line ... it didn't worked if  parenthesis are on different line

Answer (score 4):

Use the following simple perl script to remove every pair of parentheses and their content, even across multiple lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
undef $/;
$text = <>;
#Flags: g=match repeatedly; s=dot matches newline
$text =~ s/\(.*?\)//gs;
print $text;
```

If you want to fit it into the commandline, here's the one-liner version:

```
perl -p0777e 's/\(.*?\)//gs' [filename]
```

Note that it's shorter and simpler than the perl solutions. `-0777` disables the line separator (see the `-0` flag under `man perlrun`), causing the whole file to be processed in one step. Good old perl... It's also (unusually for perl :-)) more readable than messing with sed's pattern space.

Comment: thanks ... But I need to implement this using Unix only, not perl

Comment: What do you mean you "have to"? Perl is as much part of unix as sed. If you want something that fits on the commandline, I've added a version.

Answer (score 3):

To remain `\n`ew line (if parenthesis in two consequent lines)

```
sed -e 's/\(^[^)]*) *\)\|([^)]*\() *\|$\)//g' filename
```

The script consists three patterns:

- `^[^)]*) *` from line begining any symbol(s) exept `)` till `)` with `space(s)` after;
- `([^)]*` from `(` any symbol(s) exept `)`

  - till `)` with `space(s)` after; or
  - till `$` (end of line)

For multiline cases:

```
sed ':1;s/([^)]*)//g;/(/{N;b1};' filename
```

Comment: But this command is not deleting the content between the opening and closing parenthesis instead it is just removing the lines containing opening and closing parenthesis

Comment: @Priyanka Add for multilines

Comment: thank u it worked. I am new to unix scripting. need to learn alot

Comment: @Priyanka For future: it is right way to receive correct answer - post example input and desired output

Answer (score 2):

Using Gnu Sed.

`-z` option (Null separated records), sed slurps all the input as a single record. Please try:

```
sed -ze 's/([^()]*)//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line matching with sed, it's often easiest to read the whole file, and do your search/replace on the entire contents:

```
sed -n '            # disable auto-printing
  1h                # first line, move to hold space
  1!H               # not the first line, append to hold space
  ${                # at the end of file
    x               # move hold space to pattern space
    s/([^)]*)//gp   # perform search/replace and print
  }
' file
```

There are simpler(*) options:

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\([^)]+\)/,"")} 1' file
perl -0777 -pe 's/\(.*?\)//sg' file
```

<sub>(*) "simpler" *may* be in the eye of the beholder ...</sub>

Comment: Just a add On question to this... will it work if i have nested Parenthesis Staements

Comment: Nope. That kind of structure is beyond what regular expressions can handle. Once you get "nested", your language is no longer regular.